# AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS'

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, pyinstaller

Installed Django 1.10.4 and started a project by name test_py. After that created an app by name test_app1.

After creating the app planned to create a installer to run this as a standard-alone app.

Trying to make windows installer using Django 1.10.4 and pyinstaller 3.2
On executing the below command stuck with error, followed by the console output.

```
$pyinstaller --name=test_py ../test_py/manage.py

131 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.2  
131 INFO: Python: 2.7.12  
131 INFO: Platform: Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1  
132 INFO: wrote C:\MAMP\htdocs\crumbles\test_django\test_py_package\test_py.spec  
134 INFO: UPX is not available.  
137 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths  
['C:\\MAMP\\htdocs\\crumbles\\test_django\\test_py',
 'C:\\MAMP\\htdocs\\crumbles\\test_django\\test_py_package']
137 INFO: checking Analysis  
137 INFO: Building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc is non existent  
137 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...  
140 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...  
203 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc  
208 INFO: Adding Microsoft.VC90.CRT to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\python27\python.exe  
328 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.1_none_3da38fdebd0e6822.manifest  
330 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4926_none_accf10dbe1dc8ba2.manifest  
332 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4940_none_acd19a1fe1da248a.manifest  
435 INFO: Searching for assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4940_none ...  
435 INFO: Found manifest C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4940_none_08e4299fa83d7e3c.manifest  
437 INFO: Searching for file msvcr90.dll  
437 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4940_none_08e4299fa83d7e3c\msvcr90.dll  
437 INFO: Searching for file msvcp90.dll  
437 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4940_none_08e4299fa83d7e3c\msvcp90.dll  
437 INFO: Searching for file msvcm90.dll  
437 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4940_none_08e4299fa83d7e3c\msvcm90.dll  
545 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.1_none_3da38fdebd0e6822.manifest  
546 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4926_none_accf10dbe1dc8ba2.manifest  
547 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests  \amd64_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4940_none_acd19a1fe1da248a.manifest  
548 INFO: Adding redirect Microsoft.VC90.CRT version (9, 0, 21022, 8) -> (9, 0, 30729, 4940)  
5515 INFO: Caching module hooks...  
5520 INFO: Analyzing C:\MAMP\htdocs\crumbles\test_django\test_py\manage.py  
8648 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils  
8905 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   _xmlplus  
12407 INFO: Loading module hooks...  
12407 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-distutils.py"...  
12407 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sysconfig.py"...  
12407 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-django.core.management.py"...  
14320 INFO: Excluding import 'IPython'  
14322 WARNING:   Removing import django.core.management.commands.shell from module IPython  
14322 WARNING:   Removing import django.core.management.commands.shell from module IPython.IPShell  
14322 WARNING:   Removing import django.core.management.commands.shell from module IPython.start_ipython  
14323 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'Tkinter'  
14323 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'matplotlib'  
14324 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...  
14324 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-django.db.backends.py"...  
15119 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-jinja2.py"...  
15141 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-httplib.py"...  
15141 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-django.db.backends.oracle.base.py"...  
15144 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.dom.domreg.py"...  
15144 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pkg_resources.py"...  
15457 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-django.db.backends.mysql.base.py"...  
15459 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-django.core.mail.py"...  
15537 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pytz.py"...  
15617 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...  
16035 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sqlite3.py"...  
16040 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-django.py"...  
16041 INFO: Django root directory C:\MAMP\htdocs\crumbles\test_django\test_py\test_py  
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\subproc\django_import_finder.py", line 37, in <module>
        list(settings.TEMPLATE_LOADERS) + \
      File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
        return getattr(self._wrapped, name)
    AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS'
17037 INFO: Collecting Django migration scripts.  
18081 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-django.core.cache.py"...  
18119 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-psycopg2.py"...  
18121 WARNING: Hidden import "mx.DateTime" not found!  
18186 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs  
18203 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...  
18215 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_django.py'  
18217 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_pkgres.py'  
18242 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries  
32332 INFO: Looking for eggs  
32332 INFO: Using Python library C:\Windows\system32\python27.dll  
32332 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[BindingRedirect(name=u'Microsoft.VC90.CRT', language=None, arch=u'amd64', oldVersion=(9, 0, 21022, 8), newVersion=(9, 0, 30729, 4940), publicKeyToken=u'1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b')]  
32357 INFO: Warnings written to C:\MAMP\htdocs\crumbles\test_django\test_py_package\build\test_py\warntest_py.txt  
33626 INFO: checking PYZ  
33627 INFO: Building PYZ because out00-PYZ.toc is non existent  
33627 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\MAMP\htdocs\crumbles\test_django\test_py_package\build\test_py\out00-PYZ.pyz  
35328 INFO: checking PKG  
35328 INFO: Building PKG because out00-PKG.toc is non existent  
35328 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg  
35485 INFO: Bootloader c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\run.exe  
35485 INFO: checking EXE  
35486 INFO: Building EXE because out00-EXE.toc is non existent  
35486 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc  
35486 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\MAMP\htdocs\crumbles\test_django\test_py_package\build\test_py\test_py.exe  
35518 INFO: checking COLLECT  
35518 INFO: Building COLLECT because out00-COLLECT.toc is non existent  
35518 INFO: Building COLLECT out00-COLLECT.toc  
35543 INFO: Redirecting Microsoft.VC90.CRT version (9, 0, 21022, 8) -> (9, 0, 30729, 4940)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting was deprecated in Django 1.8 and removed in Django 1.10.

It looks as if pyinstaller does not support Django 1.10 (see [this issue](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2281)). Until it is fixed, you could use Django 1.8, which is an LTS (long term support) release.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file `django_import_finder.py` file, located in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\subproc`

Find the variable named as **"hiddenimports"**

```
hiddenimports = list("settings.INSTALLED_APPS") + \
                 list("settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS") + \
                 list("settings.TEMPLATE_LOADERS") + \
                 ["settings.ROOT_URLCONF"]
```

Replace the above mentioned variable data with following lines

```
hiddenimports = list(getattr(settings, "INSTALLED_APPS", [])) + \
                 list(getattr(settings, "TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS", [])) + \
                 list(getattr(settings, "TEMPLATE_LOADERS", [])) + \
                 [getattr(settings, "ROOT_URLCONF", "")]
```

This solution is taken from https://gist.github.com/sadnoodles/ceb13afe8dfcf40e92adc0dfbafface2